# Cloud video storage for web application

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, cloud, storage, nas

I created an app that records short videos and uploads them on a cloud server. Those videos are accessible via another web server on the same cloud.
Is it possibile to use a service like youtube (or similar) to store infinite videos at reasonable price?
Right now I am paying almost 130€ euros months for 500G of storage, which is the price of my Freenas server on the cloud.

Anyone knows the best way to upload many videos at lower price?

thank you!!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are **off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.